# Record Insertion - If zero insert zero else apply formula

Tags: mysql

Following is my query in which i am trying to apply formula on users.i_dob it if the insertion value is not zero else the query should insert zero. Kindly let me know how can i modify the following actual query in order to achieve my functionality thanks,

**Actual QUERY:**

```
 INSERT IGNORE into age ( i_age)
                SELECT DISTINCT FLOOR((TO_DAYS(NOW())- TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(users.i_dob))) / 365.25)
            FROM users
```

**What I am trying to do with the query:**

```
INSERT IGNORE into z_census ( i_age)
            SELECT IF (i_age == 0) i_age else FLOOR((TO_DAYS(NOW())- TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(users.i_dob))) / 365.25)
            FROM users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

```
INSERT IGNORE into z_census ( i_age)
            SELECT IF((i_age = 0), i_age, FLOOR((TO_DAYS(NOW())- TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(users.i_dob))) / 365.25))
            FROM users
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [MySQL IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) syntax.  It should look something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE into z_census (i_age)
SELECT IF(i_age=0, i_age,
    FLOOR((TO_DAYS(NOW())- TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(users.i_dob))) / 365.25))
FROM users
```